# Laravel 3 - Cascade deletes on many to many relationships

Tags: orm, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-3

I can't seem to work this out at the moment.

I have 3 tables, interests, interest_user, and users, with a many-to-many relationship setup between them.

If I delete an interest I want to make sure that any records in the pivot table are deleted as well (or else I'm going to run into errors down the line I guess).

Can this be done with $table->foreign() on the interests table (I don't think so because there's no id to reference). Otherwise do I have to loop through all the relationships when the interest is deleted and delete each pivot?

I think I'm going to encounter the same problem on a one-to-many relationship I have

One category has many interests. If I delete a category I don't think I can have a foreign key linked to interests on the category table. I'll also need to cascade a category deletion through to all the interest_user records.

Any guidance would be hugely appreciated as my brain is a little frazzled.

Cheers!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

### Many to Many:

According to the [Laravel 3 Docs on Foreign Keys](http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/schema#foreign-keys), your migration for the pivot table should be:

`$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->on_delete('cascade');`
`$table->foreign('interest_id')->references('id')->on('interests')->on_delete('cascade');`

When you delete either a user or an interest, the rows associated with that user or interested in the pivot table will be deleted.

### One to many

If you are dealing with a one-to-many (for example, users and creditcards). on the creditcards table you will have a user_id and to set up foreign key like so:

`$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->on_delete('cascade');` (basically exactly like the many-to-many)

So when you delete the user, the row(s) on the creditcards table associated with that user will be deleted as well.